# Scala immutable linked list with cycles

Tags: scala, linked-list

In Scala, I need to make an immutable linked list with cycles. Something like:

```
case class Node(element: Int, next: Node)
val linkedList = Node(1, Node(2, null))
val cycle = Node(3, cycle)

cycle.next // this should go back to the same element
```

But it doesn't work. How do I make an immutable linked list with cycles?

Answer (score 5):

Use lazy values and by-name parameters to defer initialization:

```
class Node(val element: Int, next_ : => Node) {
  lazy val next = next_
}

lazy val root: Node =
  new Node(1,
    new Node(2,
      new Node(3, root)
    )
  )

// tail-recursive print function as a bonus
def printRec(node: Node, depth: Int): Unit = if (depth > 0) {
  println(node.element)
  printRec(node.next, depth - 1)
}

printRec(root, 10)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Lazy construction:

```
scala> case class Node(element: Int)(next0: => Node) { def next = next0 }
defined class Node

scala> object X { val cycle: Node = Node(3)(cycle) }
defined object X

scala> X.cycle
res0: Node = Node(3)

scala> X.cycle.next
res1: Node = Node(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Immutable linked lists with cycles are possible if they are lazy. Scala already has support for lazy lists. They are called `Stream`s:

```
val stream: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: stream
for { i <- stream.take(10) } {
  println(i)
}
```

This will print:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
```